# Best plot for 2 categorical and 1 quantitative variable over time matplotlib

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

Currently, I have a table in the form:

```
created_date    type    category    count
2020/10/10       A         C1        2
                           C2        3
                 B         C1        2
                           C2        8
2020/10/11       A         C1        3
... and so on
```

So basically I have a df grouped by three variables i.e. time, type, and category. What I want is a way to plot it into a single graph (if possible) with the maximum amount of information.

Comment: if you just have 2 types and 2 categories, totally 4 combination, I would just do 4 line plots of cumulative sum of count, x axis being the date. if you are not caring much about the sequence of date, you can do 4 histogram of count

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, I do care about the sequence of dates and basically, I want the information like for a type A what is the cumulative count for all the categories and the individual count for each category. I was thinking about stacked multi bar charts, would that be a good option?

Answer (score 0):

You can test [seaborn.lineplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html)

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(data=your_df, x='created_date', y='count', hue='type', style='category')
```

Using this dummy data as input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'created_date': np.repeat(pd.date_range('2020-10-10', '2020-12-31'), 4),
                    'type': np.tile(np.repeat(['A', 'B'], 2), 83),
                    'category': np.tile(['C1', 'C2'], 2*83),
                    'count': np.sin(np.arange(4*83)/80+np.tile([0,1,0,1], 83))+np.tile([0,0.2,0.4,0.5], 83)
                    
                   })
```

```
  created_date type category     count
0   2020-10-10    A       C1  0.000000
1   2020-10-10    A       C2  1.048159
2   2020-10-10    B       C1  0.424997
3   2020-10-10    B       C2  1.361136
4   2020-10-11    A       C1  0.049979
5   2020-10-11    A       C2  1.073575
6   2020-10-11    B       C1  0.474930
7   2020-10-11    B       C2  1.385468
8   2020-10-12    A       C1  0.099833
9   2020-10-12    A       C2  1.096808
...
```

Here is how it looks:

[image: lineplot]